# How to copy a file from unix to windows machine, from commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, unix

How to copy a file from unix machine to windows machine, from commandline.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that, the Windows box have a shared folder. You can use smbclient command.
Which provide a FTP-like command line interface over the SMB protocol.

[This post](http://www.coolcommands.com/index.php?option=com_cccat&task=display&id=1046) provide a ready to use example, which looks a perfect answer.

If you need to copy files to or from a windows server from a unix server, you can use an utility from the Samba software suite called smbclient.

> Here is an example to copy a file to a Windows server:

```
 smbclient //WIN_SERVER/SHARE -l WIN_SERVER_IP -A AUTHFILE -c "put
 TRANSFER_FILE_LOCAL TRANSFER_FILE_REMOTE"
```

> where:
>
> WIN_SERVER = the name of your Windows server
>
> SHARE = the name of your Windows share
>
> WIN_SERVER_IP = the IP address of your Windows server
>
> AUTHFILE = full path to your authentication file name. The file
>   contents should include:
>
> ```
> username = mywinuser
> password = mywinpass
> domain = MYDOMAIN
> ```
>
> TRANSFER_FILE_LOCAL = full path to Unix file to transfer
>
> TRANSFER_FILE_REMOTE = new file name on Windows server
>
> For more help or options using smbclient, type "smbclient -h"

Comment: Top tip. I used `smbclient //winhost01/myshare -W mydomain -U myuser -c "get path\to\_readme.txt _readme.txt"`

Comment: to place the file at a certain location on Windows. Use "cd dir1/dir2; put localFile" as argument to "-c" where the desired destination is //WIN_SERVER/SHARE/dir1/dir2 and the local file to transfer is localFile.

Answer (score 1):

If your windows machine is on the same network, you can share your unix filesystem with smb and mount it on the windows machine, then use "cp" to transfer the file.

You can find information about smb for ubuntu here https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html

Comment: What if the script is running on the Unix side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PSFTP to download/upload files to / from Unix server from your Windows machine.

You may see this [guide](http://java.sg/how-to-sftp-from-windows-command-prompt-using-psftp/).

Comment: The link is dead